# bind failure: Address already in use even though recycle and reuse flags are set to 1

Tags: unix, networking, curl, tcp

Environment:

Unix  client and unix server.

Tool used : curl.

Client/Server should ignore the time wait time (2 *MSL ) when establishing connection.

This is done by executing the following commands :

sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1

sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1

Local port must be specified so that it can re-used.

Start the connection.

Example :  while [ 1 ]; do curl --local-port 9056 192.168.40.2; sleep 30; done

I am still seeing the error even though it should have ignored time wait period. 
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: "Local port must be specified so that it can re-used." It would be more to the point *not* to specify it so that the system can give you one that *isn't* in use.

Comment: OS allows reuse of ports and that what I want to test.

Comment: Why? Why do you want to ignore the TIME_WAIT period? It is there for a very good reason, in fact a security reason. What's the *actual* problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: For applications like nfs, the ports are reused which ignores the time wait. I have to do something related to that.